# How can I not have duplicate value in shopping cart made with react using Context API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopping-cart, react-context, reducers

This is the code that I used in the reducer to add items to cart, the return statement below is what I was trying to use to not allow any duplicate items in the cart but to change only the quantity of the item. But it still did not work. The quantity does update but I still end up with duplicate values. So please help me figure this out, Thx

```
export const initialState = {
    cart: []
}

const Reducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "ADD_TO_CART":
            const {id, quantity} = action.item
            let alreadyInCart = false, newQty=0
            
            state.cart.forEach(x =>{
                if(x.id === id){
                    alreadyInCart = true
                    newQty = parseInt(x.quantity+quantity)
                }
            })

            //let categories = [...new Set(Inventory.map(x=>x.category))]

            if(!alreadyInCart){
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cart: [...state.cart, action.item]
                }
            } else{
```

> ```
>            ***return {
>                   ...state,
>                    cart: [...state.cart, 
>                        {...action.item, quantity: newQty}
>                    ]
>                }***
> ```

```
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default Reducer
```

Comment: Please include complete codebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to update the existing item in the cart, or add it to the cart.

Try this.

```js
export const initialState = {
  cart: [],
};

const Reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_CART':
      const nextCart = [...state.cart];
      const existingIndex = nextCart.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.item.id);

      if (existingIndex >= 0) {
        const newQuantity = parseInt(nextCart[existingIndex].quantity + action.item.quantity);

        nextCart[existingIndex] = {
          ...action.item,
          quantity: newQuantity,
        };
      } else {
        nextCart.push(action.item);
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        cart: nextCart,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default Reducer;
```

Comment: I'm just a beginner, i really wasnot thinking of this stuff in that way at all. Thank you so much.

Comment: You’re welcome. Let me know if you need me to explain anything.

Comment: Hey, I have another question, can you help please?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/64434614/14415571?sem=2